# Questions on PPAPI

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient, ppapi

Can someone please validate the following assumptions on PPAPI?

1. PPAPI plugin needs to be compiled with Nacl compiler which puts API restrictions on it.
2. Additionally loading of PPAPI plugin seems to be only possible if they are published via Chrome Webstore
3. PPAPI will support asynchronous communication henceforth like native messaging as per https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/message-system  and as per the following page, synchronous communication using PPAPI has been discouraged.
   http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/wiki/InterfacingWithJavaScript

We have the requirement to intercept the chrome traffic, send it for analysis to native application and block it in real time depending on the result of the analysis. Tried exploring native messaging but the problem with it is that it only supports asynchronous communication and does not support following use case.

interceptHeader is the listener added  to chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders with ["blocking", "requestHeaders"] specs.

```
interceptHeaders: function(details)
{
    var verdict = false;

    //send request for scanning only if it is a POST request                         
    if (details.method == "POST")
    {
        //create new responseObject
        var responseObject = new ResponseObject();

        /use native messaging to send request for scanning
       chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.my_company.my_application',
                                          requestObject,
                                          responseObject.Callback
                                        );

        // wait for response - how to efficiently wait unitl responseObject.Callback is processed
        // so that responseObject.verdict can be used as a return value of interceptHeaders as shown below
        ??????????????           

        //update the verdict (true or false)
        verdict = responseObject.verdict;

        console.log ("verdict " + verdict + "for RequestId " + details.requestId);

        //delete the responseObject
        delete responseObject;
    }

    return {cancel: verdict};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to block on the plugin synchronously. The API is designed specifically with this requirement, both for performance, and stability reasons (supporting synchronous calls between processes means doing reentrant calls from inside blocking ones, which almost guarantees crashing or seriously confusing your code).

Comment: So is there any way to intercept traffic in chrome to analyze it in real time? From the following it seems that webpagetest used to hook in-memory ssl_Write method from the chrome dll in order to intercept the traffic (the same way Firefox exposed PR_WRITE method) but this method doesn't appear in the recent chrome versions.

http://code.google.com/p/webpagetest/source/browse/trunk/agent/wpthook/hook_nspr.cc?r=715

If the above is not possible, is there any other way for the chrome?